# json.net to System.text.json desiration for nested class in .net 5

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I am having issue.I have migrated Json.net to system.text.json.
**Json serialization and deserialization of non nested simple class types are working fine**..

Json Request:

```
{"args":{"pageIndex":1,"pageSize":10,"filteringOptions":[],"sortingOptions":[{"field":"ain","direction":"ASC"}]}}
```

For the below serialization of complex types are getting error..

```
 services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
              {
                  options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());  // Input/Output date format
              });
```

Class:

```
 public class SearchPageRequest
{
    public PageSearchArgs Args { get; set; } = new PageSearchArgs();
}
 public class PageSearchArgs
    {            
       public int PageIndex { get; set; }
       public int PageSize { get; set; }
       public PagingStrategy PagingStrategy { get; set; }
       public List<SortingOption>? SortingOptions { get; set; }   //Only List are not mapping 
       public List<FilteringOption>? FilteringOptions { get; set; }
    }


 public class SortingOption
    {
     
        public string Field { get; set; } = null!;
        //[JsonPropertyName("direction")]     tested put Json property for all propertie
        public SortingDirection Direction { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }

        public enum SortingDirection
        {
            ASC,
            DESC
        }
    }
```

i am using default case in C# Class ( Pascal case) and in angular interface ( Camelcase)..
in .net 5 and angular 10 application.

Error In model validation.

***Key:  "$.args.sortingOptions[0].direction"***     (Camelcase)

Value:The JSON value could not be converted to Application.Wrappers.Paging.SortingOption+SortingDirection. Path: $.args.sortingOptions[0].direction | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 109.

[image]

Please let me know..i am trying from 2 days..The data coming from angular slickdrid..if any changes i have to modify in c# class itlsef

What i have tried: (It is working fine in json.net)

1. Json property name i have defined as camelcase

Based on error
***$.args.sortingOptions[0].direction is not mapping to SortingOptions of direction.which is enum property..Please let me know alternate solution?***

Comment: Why don't you share with us the raw json you are trying to deserialize? The error is what it says, it cannot translate the json value to any of the values of your SortingDirection enum. This might be because the ennum members are not PascalCase as you claim but UPPERCASE.

Comment: Thanks..how to get rawJson i using angular application as front end

Comment: Use browser network log and see the request body.

Comment: Thanks.. u r right..am getting   direction: 'ASC' ..But it is coming from slickgrid...is there any option to modify ..

Comment: It depends what you're trying to achieve. If you want to set .net json serializer to case-insensitive, you can do that. Or there may be option to do it on your front-end. If you limit the problem to small issue like this, you can use Google to solve it. Or somebody might be able to help you. But when your issue requires knowledge of multiple frameworks to resolve, the probability of finding someone who can help goes down very fast.

Comment: In other words, I cannot take anything from your post and run it locally in 10 seconds. If you'd show me your json, put in a c# console app that tries to parse it and asked what to do so it parses, that's very easy to answer. I expect the same if you isolate the front-end issue.

Comment: {"args":{"pageIndex":1,"pageSize":10,"filteringOptions":[],"sortingOptions":[{"field":"ain","direction":"ASC"}]}}

Comment: Thanks a lot .. i made  [JsonIgnore]
        public SortingDirection Direction { get; set; } now  working..

Comment: Yes, except now your sorting directions will be ignored. But it's really up to you to define 'working'. Also, you can read about deserializing case-insensitive strings and enums at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#deserialization-behavior

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to  migrate Json.net to system.text.json?

According to https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/07/28/json-serializers.aspx

> If you're already using Newtonsoft.Json in an existing project, you
> likely don't need to switch. If you absolutely need high JSON
> serialization/deserialization performance, go with System.Text.

Json.net has a few convenient features, that are not available in System.Text. It is better to use the package that is more suitable for the job.

Comment: Thanks ... Now i have fixed issue using json ignore